# rvm_debug breaks teamcity agent

Tags: rvm, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I am running teamcity build agent on a ubuntu 14.04, when I started the started the agent today I got the following error:

`RPC2 buildServer.registerAgent3: org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 28: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity. 
    jetbrains.buildServer.xmlrpc.RemoteCallException: Call http://teamcityserver:8080/RPC2 buildServer.registerAgent3: org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 28: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.`

I turned out that the `env.rvm_debug` variable was set to a value that teamcity had issues encoding the xml, to solve this I've update the agent conf and set the `env.rvm_debug` to an empty string.

Do you guys have a better idea?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I added this to the end of .bash_profile

```
rvm_debug() { echo; }
export -f rvm_debug
```